# 'Error no provider for TokenGuard' when adding subroutes to guarded route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have created a angular 2/web api application in which i have a `Startpage` for which users don't have to log in unlike other parts of the applicatication.
This setup has worked for the `Startpage` component, but now I want to add a subroute `messages` to my routing module and suddenly I see the following error message in my console: `Error: no provider for TokenGuard`.
This is the contents of my routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: MainNavigationComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'messages',
                    component: MessagesComponent,
                    resolve: { connection: ConnectionResolver }
                },
                {
                    path: 'todos',
                    component: TodosComponent,
                    resolve: { connection: ConnectionResolver }
                },
                {
                    path: 'startpage',
                    canActivate: [TokenGuard],
                    canActivateChild: [TokenGuard],
                    component: StartpageComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'messages',
                            component: MessagesComponent
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];
```

`TokenGuard`

```
import {StartpageService} from 'startpage.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router,ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class TokenGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
constructor(
    private startPageService: StartpageService,
    private router: Router
) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.startPageService.validateToken();
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
}
}
```

Comment: have u added `TokenGuard` to the providers array of your NgModule ?

Comment: Yes I have. When I remove the subroute `messages` under `startpage`, the `TokenGuard` is executed and the serverside validation method is executed. but now it doesnt.

Comment: can u pls post code for `TokenGuard` ?

Comment: Added code for `TokenGuard`. Any `console.log` added to the `TokenGuard` are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

add TokenGuard to app.module providers

```
@NgModule({
  .....,
  providers:[..., TokenGuard]
})
```